# How to organize REST-API versioning the right way?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm building a website's backend on Django-REST-FrameWork, and currently I have the following structure (below is only a part of it obviously):

```
project_root:
    apps:
        app1:
            models.py
            serializers.py
            views.py
            urls.py
        app2:
            models.py
            serializers.py
            views.py
            urls.py
    urls:
        urls.py - (Main project urls file)
```

An endpoints:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/app1/
http://localhost:8000/api/app2/
```

How to add versioning ? should I just add an "v2" folder to each app ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For every new version of your api, you should add new endpoint in your main `urls.py` file like this.

```
url(r'^api/v1.0/app1/', include('app1.urls', namespace='v1.0')),
url(r'^api/v1.1/app1/', include('app1.urls', namespace='v1.1')),

url(r'^api/v1.0/app2/', include('app2.urls', namespace='v1.0')),
url(r'^api/v1.2/app2/', include('app2.urls', namespace='v1.1')),
```

Your should add this in your restframework settings.

```
'DEFAULT_VERSIONING_CLASS': 'rest_framework.versioning.NamespaceVersioning'
```

You can access current version in your view by `request.version`.